# Scheduled notification not working in android 9.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Whenever I am using Alarm Manager in my Local Notification code,it is working fine with Android version 8.0 and below. But , 
its not working for Android version 9.0.

Alarm Manager Code ::

```
    var intent = CreateIntent(id);
        var localNotification = new LocalNotification();
        localNotification.Title = title;
        localNotification.Body = body;
        localNotification.Id = id;
        localNotification.NotifyTime = notifyTime;

        if (_notificationIconId != 0)
        {
            localNotification.IconId = _notificationIconId;
        }
        else
        {
            localNotification.IconId = Resource.Drawable.notification_bg;
        }

        var serializedNotification = SerializeNotification(localNotification);
        intent.PutExtra(ScheduledAlarmHandler.LocalNotificationKey, serializedNotification);

        Random generator = new Random();
        _randomNumber = generator.Next(100000, 999999).ToString("D6");

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Application.Context, Convert.ToInt32(_randomNumber), intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);
        var alarmManager = GetAlarmManager();
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliSeconds, pendingIntent);
```

And, when I am implementing the same code with Notification Manager using ChannelID . So, the notification is popping up in 
Android Version 9.0 and below. 
But, if I want to set a particular delivery time to show up the Notification, then it doesn't work here. It delivers immediately.

Notification Manager Code ::

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.Immutable);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context, channelId)

            .SetVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100 })
            .SetPriority(1)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(title)               
            .SetContentText(body)
            .SetWhen(totalMilliSeconds)               
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_bg)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);

Notification notification = builder.Build();
        manager.Notify(channelId, messageId, notification);
```

So, is there a way so that I can implement this in Android Version 9.0 and below???

Comment: According to the Android docs, Scheduling Alarm requirements haven't changed since Android 6.0 (API level 23) https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html It doesnt seem like you are implementing alarms in the right way, as you can see there are quite a few differences

Comment: You should schedule it using the WorkManager: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-workmanager/